# How can I re-enable the Stripe button after getting declined?

Tags: stripe-payments

You can find an example here: https://stripe.com/docs/button

Using `4000 000 0000 0002` and submitting will cause the button to be disabled.

I'm using AJAX and POSTing the token (along with other form elements). In the event someone enters a declined credit card number, how can I re-enabled it without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe updated their button to V2 and it's now called Checkout. You can now add you own button and have more control.

Answer (score -1):

You can update your button's `disabled` attribute. For example, with jQuery:

```
$('#payButton').attr('disabled', false)
```

This will re-enable the button to accept your customers' payment information.

Comment: You cannot target the button because it's in an iFrame and you cannot access it via jQuery.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about the confusion there: I was referencing the latest Checkout version (with custom button support). Your self-answer is much clearer; thanks!